# python scrape next strings to a given string

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have +1000 txt files to scrape (Python). I already created the `file_list` variable that lists all the .txt file paths. I have five fields to scrape: file_form, date, company, company id, and price range. For the first four variables I have no issue since they're very structured in separate lines at the beginning of each .txt file:

```
FILE FORM:      10-K
DATE:           20050630
COMPANY:        APPLE INC
COMPANY CIK:    123456789
```

I used the following code for these four ones:

```
    import sys, os, re
    exemptions=[]    
        for eachfile in file_list:
                line2 = ""  # for the following loop I need the .txt in lines. Right now, the file is read one in all. Create var with lines
                with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        line2 = line2 + line  # append each line. Shortcut: "line2 += line"
                        if "FILE FORM" in line:
                            exemptions.append(line.strip('\n').replace("FILE FORM:", "")) #append line stripping 'S-1\n' from field in + replace FILE FORM with blanks
                        elif "COMPANY" in line:
                            exemptions.append(line.rstrip('\n').replace("COMPANY:", ""))  # rstrip=strips trailing characters '\n'
                        elif "DATE" in line:
                            exemptions.append(line.rstrip('\n').replace("DATE:", ""))  # add field 
                        elif "COMPANY CIK" in line:
                            exemptions.append(line.rstrip('\n').replace("COMPANY CIK:", ""))  # add field
print(exemptions)
```

These gives me a list `exemptions` with all the associated values as in the above example. However, the "price range" field is found in the middle of the .txt file in sentences like:

```
We anticipate that the initial public offering price will be between $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and
$&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;per share.
```

And I don't know how to keep the `$whateveritis;and $whateveritis;per share.` as my last fifth variable. Good news is that a lot of files use the same structure, where sometimes instead of the "&nbsp" I have $amounts. Example: `We anticipate that the initial public offering price will be between $12.00&nbsp;and $15.00&nbsp; per share.`.

I would like this "12.00;and;15.00" as my fifth variable in the `exemptions` list (or something similar I can easily work afterwards in a csv file).

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have already imported regular expressions so why don't you use that? A regex such as `\$[\d.]+\&nbsp;and \$[\d.]+` should match the prices and then you can easily refine it from there:

```py
import sys, os, re
    exemptions=[]    
    for eachfile in file_list:
            line2 = ""
            with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    line2 = line2 + line

                    m = re.search('\$[\d.]+\&nbsp;and \$[\d.]+', line)

                    if "FILE FORM" in line:
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    elif m:
                        exemptions.append(m.group(0))   # m.group(0) will be the first occurrence and you can refine it from there

print(exemptions)
```